# Showing a circle crop in UIImagePicker edit view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the default ios camera in my app. I don't want to create an overlay for the whole camera, but I would like to change something the edit view that shows after the user takes a photo. Normally, it shows a square to crop, but I would like it to show a circle how would I do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code or show some research you've done.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing. UIImagePicker.allowsEditing shows a view to crop, move, scale but it's rectangular, not circular like the native Contacts App. Why wouldn't Apple just share this functionality?